# Matrix multiplication not working- Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am begginer in using tensorflow and am using for a school project. Here I am attempting to make a house identifier, where I made some data on an excel sheet, turned it into a csv file and I was testing if the data would be read. The data was read but it produces multiple errors when I do the matrix multiplication and says.... "ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 0 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [], [1,1]." Thank you so much!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = dir_path+ "\House Price Data .csv"
w1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
w2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1])) #Feature 1's weight
w3=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1])) #Feature 1's weight
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1])) #bias for various features
x1= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 1])
x2= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 1])
x3= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 1])
Y= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 1])
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with open(filename) as inf:
        # Skip header
        next(inf)
        for line in inf:
            # Read data, using python, into our features
            housenumber, x1, x2, x3, y_ = line.strip().split(",")
            x1 = float(x1)
            product = tf.matmul(x1, w1)
            y = product + b
```

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting the x1 variable.

Comment: The input from the csv file is what I wanted the x1 vatiable to be. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I used the x1 as a testing example when debugging it

Comment: I think you may need to find an intro to tensorflow tutorial. It seems like you are trying to treat tensorflow commands like regular python commands and it's not like that.

Comment: Honestly, I am quite familiar with Java and I am new to this, but I need to do this for a school project. Can you please explain what is wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aaron is right, you are overwriting the variables when you loading the data from the csv file.

You need to save the loaded value into a separate variable, say `_x1` instead of `x1`, and then use feed_dict to feed the value to the placeholder. And because the shape of your `x1` is `[None,1]`, you need to convert your string scalar `_x1` into a float with the same shape, which is `[1,1]` in this case.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
filename = dir_path+ "\House Price Data .csv"
w1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1])) #bias for various features
x1= tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 1])

y_pred = tf.matmul(x1, w1) + b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer())
    with open(filename) as inf:
        # Skip header
        next(inf)
        for line in inf:
            # Read data, using python, into our features
            housenumber, _x1, _x2, _x3, _y_ = line.strip().split(",")
            sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={x1:[[float(_x1)]]})
```